# Configure Tomcat 8 for HTTP/2.0 for HTTP(not https) calls

Tags: java, spring, http, tomcat, http2

We have our legacy Tomcat server on version `8.5.81`

We plan to upgrade to HTTP/2 for quicker api response times (optimization)

Following configuration has been applied at `server.xml`

```
        <Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   redirectPort="8443">
            <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        </Connector>
```

But still calls remain on HTTP/1.1

Need help for ..

1. **What more changes should be done to achieve HTTP/2 at server ?**
2. Most of our calls are on 8080(http). Very less are on 443(https). My internet search  suggested samples where it appears that HTTP2 would be applicable only on HTTPS for tomcat 8.5 series.
   **How do I achieve this for both HTTP & HTTPS ?**

Answer (score 2):

1. No more changes needed. Tomcat offers both protocols depending on the request (see below).
2. HTTP/2 supports both http and https ([Does HTTP/2 require encryption?](https://http2.github.io/faq/))

The request must explicitly ask for `HTTP/2` protocol, either through a `HTTP/1.1` protocol upgrade or directly

**With protocol upgrade**:
Request: `GET /sample/hello HTTP/1.1`
Header : `Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings`

```
curl --verbose --http2 http://localhost:8080/sample/hello
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /sample/hello HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
> Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
> Upgrade: h2c
> HTTP2-Settings: AAMAAABkAAQCAAAAAAIAAAAA
> 
< HTTP/1.1 101 
< Connection: Upgrade
< Upgrade: h2c
< Date: Thu, 24 Aug 2023 18:11:37 GMT
* Received 101, Switching to HTTP/2
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< content-length: 311
< date: Thu, 24 Aug 2023 18:11:37 GMT
(response redacted)
```

**Direct request**:
Request: `GET /sample/hello HTTP/2`

```
 curl --verbose --http2-prior-knowledge http://localhost:8080/sample/hello
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* h2h3 [:method: GET]
* h2h3 [:path: /sample/hello]
* h2h3 [:scheme: http]
* h2h3 [:authority: localhost:8080]
* h2h3 [user-agent: curl/8.0.1]
* h2h3 [accept: */*]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x558d436ecf40)
> GET /sample/hello HTTP/2
> Host: localhost:8080
> user-agent: curl/8.0.1
> accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< content-length: 311
< date: Thu, 24 Aug 2023 18:14:01 GMT
< 
(response redacted)
```

If HTTP/2 is not explicitly requested, HTTP/1.1 will be served

```
curl --verbose http://localhost:8080/sample/hello
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /sample/hello HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 311
< Date: Thu, 24 Aug 2023 18:18:39 GMT
<
```

Tested with this configuration

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443">
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    </Connector>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting below error on doing curl with --http2-prio-knowledge

Comment: * Send failure: Connection reset by peer
* Failed sending HTTP2 data
* Connection #0 to host rtp-dev.indepay.com left intact
curl: (55) Send failure: Connection reset by peer

Comment: Try `--http2` also and check tomcat logs. May be there's some clue why connection was terminated.